# How to evaluate an expression using β reduction in lambda calculus?

Tags: lambda, programming-languages, lambda-calculus, formal-languages, reduction

I want to evaluate the following expression:

```
(λx.y)((λz.zz)(λw.w))
```

using **β reduction** .

The answer is:

```
(λx.y)((λz.zz)(λw.w)) ->
(λx.y)((λw.w)(λw.w)) ->
(λx.y)(λw.w) -> y
```

But I don't understand the 2nd phase:

From here: `(λx.y)((λz.zz)(λw.w))` to here `(λx.y)((λw.w)(λw.w))`

What are we doing there? From my understanding, I need to use the **α-equivalence** rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beta reduction allows a term (λx.t)s to be reduced to t[x := s]. In your problem step, x is z, t is zz, and s is λw.w. So here t[x := s] is zz[z := λw.w], which is (λw.w)(λw.w).

Answer (score 3):

The reduction you propose, is reduction by-value.

```
 (λx.y) z -> y[x/z] IF z is a value.
```

You could reduce directly to y using the reduction by name

```
 (λx.y) z -> y[x/z].
```

To answer your question:

```
(λx.y)((λz.zz)(λw.w)) -> (λx.y)((λw.w)(λw.w))
```

Because

```
 ( (λz.zz)(λw.w) ) is not a value (as (λx.y)z is never a value.)
```

And because

```
  (zz)[z/(λw.w)] i.e.substitute every occurence of z with (λw.w) leads to 

  (λw.w)(λw.w)
```